# Using unbound control value in an SQL statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-forms

I would just like to use an MS Access unbound control as criteria in my VBA SQL command.

The unbound control is named `AssignInvoice`

Here is what I have:

```vb
Private Sub Command64_Click()
    Dim InvNum As String
    
    InvNum = Me.AssignInvoice.Value
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Orders (InvoiceNumber, CompanyName, PurchaseOrderNumber) values (AssignInvoice.Value, CompanyName.Value, PurchaseOrderNumber.Value)"
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Order Details] ( InvoiceNumber, ItemNumber, [Product Description], [Size], Quantity, UnitPrice )SELECT [SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum, [SalesOrder Details].ItemNumber, [SalesOrder Details].[Product Description], [SalesOrder Details].Size, [SalesOrder Details].Quantity, [SalesOrder Details].UnitPrice FROM [SalesOrder Details] WHERE [SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum = InvNum"
End Sub
```

The problem is when I click the button, Access asks for the `InvNum` parameter. Apparently I am not saving the form text box to the variable `InvNum` correctly, or syntax error?

When I enter the parameter the SQL statement ends up working correctly.

Hoping someone can clear this up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable and control values to the SQL string

```
Private Sub Command64_Click()

Dim InvNum As String

InvNum = Me.AssignInvoice.Value

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Orders (InvoiceNumber, CompanyName, PurchaseOrderNumber) values ('" & Me.AssignInvoice.Value & "', '" & Me.CompanyName.Value & "', '" & Me.PurchaseOrderNumber.Value & "')"
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Order Details] ( InvoiceNumber, ItemNumber, [Product Description], [Size], Quantity, UnitPrice )SELECT [SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum, [SalesOrder Details].ItemNumber, [SalesOrder Details].[Product Description], [SalesOrder Details].Size, [SalesOrder Details].Quantity, [SalesOrder Details].UnitPrice FROM [SalesOrder Details] WHERE [SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum = '" & InvNum & "'"
End Sub
```

Number values can be directly concatenated to the string

String values need to be enclosed in single quotes`'`, or double quotes`"`

Date values should be enclosed in `#`

Generic example

`INSERT INTO TABLE (NumberField, StringField, DateField) VALUES (NumberValue, 'StringValue', #DateValue#)`

You can store the SQL string in a string variable and use `Debug.Print` to see the resulting string in the Immediate Window for debugging / troubleshooting purposes.

```
Dim strSQL as String

strSQL = "INSERT INTO Orders (InvoiceNumber, CompanyName, PurchaseOrderNumber) values ('" & Me.AssignInvoice.Value & "', '" & Me.CompanyName.Value & "', '" & Me.PurchaseOrderNumber.Value & "')"

Debug.Print strSQL
```

Comment: Syntax error on run...
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO [Order Details] ( InvoiceNumber, ItemNumber, [Product Description], [Size], Quantity, UnitPrice )SELECT [SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum, [SalesOrder Details].ItemNumber, [SalesOrder Details].[Product Description], [SalesOrder Details].Size, [SalesOrder Details].Quantity, [SalesOrder Details].UnitPrice FROM [SalesOrder Details] WHERE [SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum = " & InvNum


Here is my error (0test was the form value btw): 
syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum =0test'

Comment: I've edited the answer. Since your `InvNum` is a string, you need to add the quotes around the value while concatenating the string.

Comment: What are the data types of three controls values, which you're passing to the SQL string? From your comments `AssignInvoice` control contains a string. What are the data types of the other two controls: `CompanyName` and `PurchaseOrderNumber`?

Comment: They are all strings

Comment: Help is much appreciated BTW

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect all control to contain strings. You just need to make sure that the resulting control value is enclosed in quotes `'`.

Comment: SOLVED! I replaced the back for the statement with your solution:
WHERE [SalesOrder Details].AssignedInvNum = '" & InvNum & "'"
Many thanks to you!